# Nodejs Extra Data in FormData

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am sending a http request with a file to Sharepoint. Some file types, such as png or other images become corrupted and unreadable. When looking at those I see extra object data at the head e.g.

```
----------------------------826320949470377643449533
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="mypdf.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

and at the bottom:

```
----------------------------826320949470377643449533--
```

Is there a way to prevent this? The code I am using looks like:

```
const contentType = mime.contentType(fileName);
const data = new FormData();
data.append('file',fs.createReadStream(path));
const fileSize = req.headers['content-length']
fs.promises.file(file)).size
const fileSizeLessByte = fileSize-1;
const contentRange = 'bytes 0-'+fileSizeLessByte+'/'+fileSize;
const contentLength = fileSize;

var config = {
    method: 'put',
    url: uploadUrl,
    headers: { 
      'Content-Range': contentRange,
      'Content-Length': contentLength,
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    data : data
  };
```

Comment: What you see is the headers for the multipart form data you requested in your `config` object. It's how you upload files. A nodejs program can *receive* this data through the use of the [multer package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). Other languages have their ways of handling it. You didn't tell us what language you use to receive the data you put, so it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: I am sending it to Sharepoint using microsoft's graph api

Comment: The multipart protocol in http handles content lengths and ranges for you. Try eliminating references to `Content-Length` and `Content-Range` from your code. Read up on using axios to sent multipart data.

Comment: I have to set the length and range due to the need to separate large files into multiple uploads

Comment: OK, but if you set length and range don't use multipart. They're mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to get this working by using readFileSync instead of FormData and not using the multipart content type as O. Jones suggested:

```
 const contentType = mime.contentType(fileName);
 const fileStream = fs.readFileSync(path);
 const fileSize = Buffer.byteLength(fileStream);
 const fileSizeLessByte = fileSize-1
 const contentRange = 'bytes 0-'+fileSizeLessByte+'/'+fileSize;
 const contentLength = fileSize;

 const config = {
     method: 'put',
     url: uploadUrl,
     headers: { 
         'Content-Type': contentType,
         'Content-Range': contentRange,
         'Content-Length': contentLength
     },
     data: fileStream
    };
```